Pyspark read csv count incorrect
I'm trying to read a csv file in databricks using Pyspark while providing a schema. If the schema of a record does not match then those records are quarantined. When I provide the wrong schema it correctly quarantines all the records but the dataframe count is incorrect and shows the actual count from the file. The cluster I am using has DBR 14.3 LTS.
file_path = "dbfs:/FileStore/something.csv"
file_type = "csv"
df = (
    spark.read.format(file_type)
    .schema(schema)
    .option(
        "badRecordsPath",
        f"/tmp/badrecords/",
    )
    .option("header", True)
    .option("encoding", "iso-8859-1")
    .option("sep", ",")
    .load(file_path)
)
df.show()
print(df.count())

Output:

Is this expected. How do I get the correct count?

it's possibly https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-46862, per the 14.3 page it's not listed as patched yet.
